# Logstash grok pattern for the below log message

Tags: logstash-grok

I wanted to extract the below enclosed in the `""` pattern from the log message using grok pattern. Could anybody help in providing the grok pattern?

```
"2015/02/24 13:44:39" - Shell - (stdout) 2015/02/24 13:44:39 - "DIF_MainJob" - "Start of job execution"

"2015/02/25 13:01:39" - "SR_Incremental_Load" - "Start of job execution"
```

Comment: You can try a grok constructor like: http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/constructionstep and debugger like: https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can break this in two steps, first match complete logs line and **second**  remove unwanted part.
I tested on my local elk setup, use below configuration, may helpful to you.

```
filter{
 grok {
  match => { "message" => "\"%{DATA:my_date}\" - %{DATA:dropword} - \"%{DATA:phrase_1}\" - \"%{DATA:phrase_2}\"" }
 }
 mutate {
   remove_field => ["dropword"]
 }
```

}

Attaching screenshot from my Kibana
[image]
[image]